# What's the Unicode code point for [ \u8D27 ]?

Tags: java, unicode, point

I want to find out if a Chinese character can be displayed, the unidode for it is "\u8D27", how to use the Java Font method canDisplay ? It takes an int, but "8D27" is not an integer, how does it work, do I need another method to translate "8D27" to an int then use canDisplay ? If so how to translate it ?

Edit :
To be more precise, how would a method below look like ?

```
boolean checkFonts(String inputUnicode)
{
  ... what goes here ??? ...
}
```

So if I call : checkFonts("\u8D27") , I can get a yes no answer.

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canDisplay()` method also accepts a `char`, so why not just get the first character of the string:

```
return font.canDisplay(inputUnicode.charAt(0));
```

And FWIW, you can convert between `char` and `int` just by casting:

```
int codePoint = 0x8D27;
char myCharacter = (char) codePoint;
```

Comment: Great, how to convert "\u8D27" to int in my Java program ?

Comment: String character = "\u8D27"; int codepoint = (int) character.charAt(0);

Answer (score 4):

8D27 is in hex, so you can write `0x8D27` as a literal.

e.g.

```
private int codePoint = 0x8D27;
```

The `\uXXXX` syntax represents the character *itself* at that code point and is used such that you can express Unicode characters in ASCII.